# Rails 5: Iugu e pagamento recorrente

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagamento-online

Procurei na documentação do Iugu qual a função em Rails chamo para criar um pagamento recorrente no iugu, mas nao consegui encontrar. Alguem pode me dar uma luz sobre isso? Lá tem `Iugu::Subscription.create`, mas gostaria da função especifica para pagamentos recorrentes e seus parametros com valores e etc. O [repositorio da gem](https://github.com/iugu/iugu-ruby) do iugu também não ajuda muito, pois tem pouca documentação, e a documentação oficial da apenas o retorno da api.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para criar assinaturas recorrentes, você deve vinculá-la a um [plano](https://dev.iugu.com/v1.0/reference#criar-2).

Answer (score 0):

Fernando esta parte de recorrente é bem tranquilo. Você deve usar é o Iugu::Subscription.create mesmo, basta passar os dados do plano que quer associar e pronto.. a Iugu vai criar a assinatura recorrente.
Eu fiz em NodeJS e está tudo funionando perfeitamente. Se precisar de alguma ajuda posso tentar ajudar. meu email é cleytonb40@gmail.com